# Semver minor and patch digit update logic

Tags: javascript, git, package, semantic-versioning, conventional-commits

I'm writing a script that bumps up the package version based on the difference in commits between the `master` and `current` branch.
I'm using `conventional commits` to decide which number to update.

---

Let's say, I have **1.0.0** by default

- `BREAKING CHANGE:` updates major +1, and leaves other digits untouched even if there were some other changes, so I get **2.0.0**
- `feat:` updates minor +1, and we would get **1.1.0**
- `fix:` updated patch +1, and gives us **1.0.1**

---

I have a couple of questions regarding such a versioning method:

1. If I have several commits on the `current` branch with the `feat:` or `fix:` should I upgrade the minor/patch version according to the number of these commits or should it be only +1 ?

*e.g. There are **3** commits with `feat:` on the `current` branch, when I merge branch to `master` should the version be **1.4.0** or just **1.1.0** ?*

2. Should I count `fix:` if I had `feat:` already?

*e.g. There is **1** `feat:` and **1** `fix:`, when merging to `master` should the version become **1.1.1** or **1.1.0** ?*

Comment: You only need to iterate one step, if you're at 1.0.0 now the next release would either be 1.0.1, 1.1.0 or 2.0.0 depending on the "biggest" change. You wouldn't go to 3.3.1 to represent three new features, two breaking changes and a bugfix, you'd just go to 2.0.0 (but you might choose to _also_ release 1.0.1 and/or 1.1.0 if the relevant changes can be backported).

Comment: @jonrsharpe , thank you, could you please make it into the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semver does a reset in two cases:

1. With the more important change. Ex: 1.4.3 -> 1.5.0 -> 2.0.0.
2. And when released, it takes the most important one.
   Ex: `master` is at 1.0.0. You have 5 breaking changes, multiple minors and patches on the `current` branch. It takes only 1 breaking change into consideration and makes 1.0.0 -> 2.0.0.

Well it's logically the best way as the user of the app doesn't care about the process you have been through in the development.